# specific perl regex string in brackets after keyword

Tags: regex, perl

I need help please with an perl regex;
My logs lines contains a `User='(string)@(realm)'` where i would only need the string in the first bracket after `User=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ...
my $line = q[User='(string)@(realm)'];
$line =~ /User='\((\w+)\)@\((\w+)\)'/;
print $1; # will print string;
print $2; # will print realm;
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape parentheses as they have a special meaning in regexes - they create capture groups:

```
my $line = q{User='(string)@(realm)'};
my ($user, $realm) = $line =~ /User='\((.*)\)@\((.*)\)'/;
print "USER: $user.\nREALM: $realm.\n";
```